# How can I embed a formula in RDLC that will perform after exporting as Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, excel-formula, export, rdlc

I know that I can get the summary by using formula in rdlc. But I want to know a way how can I perform a percentage counting in a excel after it export in the rdlc report. I will get the result in the excel when I give something input. It's only for the excel.

Here my main target is to do some calculation after exporting the excel from rdlc report only when user puts some input there.

Comment: As far i know it's not possible by using default excel renderer. But there is a third party excel rederer that supposed to work as your requirement. Never tried it though. Here is the link: http://cre4ssrs.codeplex.com/